# Generate an afilliation graphic with two bipartite graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a dataset in R with 3 categories, 10 features and 3 entities. The affiliation of the entities and categories to the features are given as values between -1 and 1. 
My aim is to illustrate the data in a graphic as follows:

[image: Graphic for illustration]

I created this using Inkscape. My question is whether this is possible using latex or should I try to achieve this in R (and transfer this question to another forum)?

EDIT: Following the inputs below and modifying @guilherme-z-santos example, I was able to create the following table:

```
\definecolor{notatall}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{verymuch}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\newcommand*{\drawconnections}[3][west]{\draw (#2) foreach \i/\j in {#3}{ edge[verymuch!\j!notatall] (feat-\i.#1)};}
\usepackage{arrayjob}

\newarray\features
\readarray{features}{Feature-1&Feature-2&Feature-3&Feature-4&Feature-5&Feature-6&Feature-7&Feature-8&Feature-9&Feature-10}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
    \begin{scope}[font=\itshape]
      \node (feat-1) {\features(1)};
      \foreach \i[remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,10}{\node[below=5mm of feat-\lasti] (feat-\i) {\features(\i)};};
    \end{scope}
    \node[left] (cat-2) at ([xshift=-3cm]$(feat-1)!.5!(feat-10)$) {Category 2};
    \node[above=2cm of cat-2] (cat-1) {Category 1};
    \node[below=2cm of cat-2] (cat-3) {Category 3};
    \node[above right] (ent-1) at ([shift={(3cm,1.5cm)}]$(feat-1)!.5!(feat-10)$) {Entity 1};
    \node[below=3cm of ent-1] (ent-2) {Entity 2};
    \node[above=8mm of feat-1, left color=notatall,right color=verymuch, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=6pt, inner sep=0pt] (shade bar) {};
    \begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
      \node[above] at (shade bar.north west) {-1};
      \node[below] at (shade bar.south west) {not at all};
      \node[above] at (shade bar.north) {0};
      \node[below] at (shade bar.south) {undecided};
      \node[above] at (shade bar.north east) {1};
      \node[below] at (shade bar.south east) {very much};
    \end{scope}
    \drawconnections{cat-1.east}{1/10,2/80,3/20,4/100,5/0,6/30,7/40,8/90,9/10,10/70};
    \drawconnections{cat-2.east}{1/20,2/40,3/0,4/10,5/0,6/100,7/20,8/10,9/90,10/20};
    \drawconnections{cat-3.east}{1/10,2/80,3/20,4/100,5/0,6/30,7/40,8/90,9/10,10/70};
    \drawconnections[east]{ent-1.west}{1/10,2/80,3/20,4/100,5/0,6/30,7/40,8/90,9/10,10/70};
    \drawconnections[east]{ent-2.west}{1/30,2/80,3/20,4/70,5/40,6/100,7/40,8/10,9/40,10/20};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also if someone could indicate a name for these kind of graphics would be appreciated, as I made this kind of from the top of my head...

Comment: Ignoring the color, you have three sets A, B, and C  with A & B forming a bipartite graph and B & C forming another bipartite graph.

Comment: The short answer to your direct question is "yes, you could draw that in any of LaTeX-friendly drawing systems".    You might find it easier in one that lets you draw it directly (TikZ, Metapost, Asymptote, etc) rather than one that plots charts (PGFPlots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can translate the -1 to 1 scale to be 0 to 100, you can pass these numbers in a list as a color mixture percentage using `foreach`, the following was produced by the below MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifnodedefined[3]{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\definecolor{notatall}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{verymuch}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\newcommand*{\drawconnections}[3][west]{\draw (#2) foreach \j[count=\i from 1] in {#3}{\ifnodedefined{feat-\i}{edge[verymuch!\j!notatall] (feat-\i.#1)}{}};}
\newcommand{\drawfeatures}[1]{\foreach \feat[count=\i from 1, remember=\i as \lasti (initially 0)] in {#1}{\ifnum\i=1\node (feat-1) {\feat} \else \node[below=5mm of feat-\lasti] (feat-\i) {\feat}\fi;\global\let\totalfeat\i}}
\begin{document}
  \sffamily
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
    \begin{scope}[font=\itshape]
        \drawfeatures{a feature, another feature, more feature, no more features, lied ;-), foo, bar}
    \end{scope}
    \node[left] (cat-2) at ([xshift=-3cm]$(feat-1)!.5!(feat-\totalfeat)$) {Category 2};
    \path let \p1=($(feat-1)-(feat-\totalfeat)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in%
        node[above=\n1/4 of cat-2] (cat-1) {Category 1}%
        node[below=\n1/4 of cat-2] (cat-3) {Category 3}%
        ([xshift=3cm]$(feat-1)!.5!(feat-\totalfeat)$) coordinate (tmp)%
        node[above right=\n1/6 and 0pt of tmp] (ent-1) {Entity 1}%
        node[below=\n1/3 of ent-1] (ent-2) {Entity 2};
    \node[above=8mm of feat-1, left color=notatall,right color=verymuch, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=6pt, inner sep=0pt] (shade bar) {};
    \begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
      \foreach \uptext/\bottomtext/\loc in {-1/not at all/ west,0/undecided/,1/very much/ east}{
        \node[above] at (shade bar.north\loc) {\uptext};
        \node[below] at (shade bar.south\loc) {\bottomtext};}
    \end{scope}
    \drawconnections{cat-1.east}{10,80,20,100,0,30,40,90,10,70};
    \drawconnections{cat-2.east}{20,40,0,10,0,100,20,10,90,20};
    \drawconnections{cat-3.east}{10,80,20,100,0,30,40,90,10,70};
    \drawconnections[east]{ent-1.west}{10,80,20,100,0,30,40,90,10,70};
    \drawconnections[east]{ent-2.west}{30,80,20,70,40,100,40,10,40,20};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT:

A second approach requested by the OP is to have a color scale of more than two colors, in this case, the `0` color would be white, but any will do. As there are two colors at hand an `\ifnum` must be used to separate the scale, that is (translated to percentage) from 0 to 50 will be going from blue to white, and from 50 to 100 will be going from white to red, translated to TeX that's

```
\ifnum\j>50%
   let \n1={int(2*(\j-50))} in% this is rescaling the 0-50 to be 0-100 or else there'd be no full red only 50/50
      edge[verymuch!\n1!undecided] (feat-\i.#1)%
\else%
   let \n1={int(2*(50-\j))} in% the same here
      edge[notatall!\n1!undecided] (feat-\i.#1)%
\fi
```

Replacing the code `edge[verymuch!\j!notatall] (feat-\i.#1)` inside the `\drawconnections` command from the MWE by the above snippet and defining the color `undecided` with `\definecolor{undecided}{RGB}{255,255,255}` yields (other colors can be experimented with):

[image]

#### Comment

Perhaps an even better solution (to the white middle color) would be to use `opacity` (also setting the `line cap=round` yields better looking results):

```
\ifnum\j>50%
   let \n1={2*(100-\j)/100} in% this is rescaling the 0-50 to be 0-100 or else there'd be no full red only 50/50
      edge[verymuch, opacity=\n1, line cap=round] (feat-\i.#1)%
\else%
   let \n1={2*(50-\j)/100} in% the same here
      edge[notatall, opacity=\n1, line cap=round] (feat-\i.#1)%
\fi
```

Comment: thanks @guilherme-z-santos, this looks good and I can understand most of the code. The only things I'm struggling is how to have the features in a separate list like `{name-of-feature, another-name, additional-name, ...}` and have the names referred instead of the `{feature \i}`. Was trying to find answer on how to index arrays but couldn't implemented them in your example successfully.

Comment: You should look for how foreach statements work. In this example I'm iterating \i through the list {1,...,10}. But you can iterate \i through a list of text entries too, then you'll need to use the counter option of the foreach statement to properly name the nodes.

Comment: Merci mille for heads up! Got it working and provided an example using `arrayjob`. Might be more elegant ways but does the job!

Comment: @sesselastronaut, check updated code! Does not get more automated than this: you can now give the features as a list of text. The category and Entities nodes are automatically positioned and when drawing the colored edges the `\drawconnection` macro tests if the node `feat-\i` has been defined, if yes it draws the edge if not it skippes it, so if you give  list too big it will ignore it. Hope you like it `;D`

Comment: @guilherme-z-santos both thumbs up for that! Can't get more generic!

Comment: @guilherme-z-santos I was plotting it with the actual data and  came to the conclusion for readability it would be nice to have white in the middle of the gradient. In case of the `\node` command defining the gradient it's straightforward using the `middle color = white` command. However for the `\drawconnections` as defined I'm struggling to implement it. Guess the crucial point is how to get the very elegant solution of `edge[verymuch!\j!notatall]` considering the gradient with three colours. If you have a pointer how that could be accomplished I would appreciate it.

Comment: @sesselastronaut, then you have a problem, because you're working not with one color scale, but two (one between -1 and 0 and other between 0 and 1) so you have to separate the cases with an `\ifnum\j>50`. I've added and EDIT showing how this can be done.

Comment: @sesselastronaut I have realized what you're looking for, take a look at the *comment* i left within the last part of the answer, I think that yields the best looking Picture for your purpose! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a beginning in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using the [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) package.  Compile with `lualatex`.  The Metapost `boxes` library provides the `boxit` functions;  the documentation for it is [here](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input boxes;
beginfig(1);

    boxit.c1("Category 1");
    boxit.c2("Category 2");
    boxit.c3("Category 3");

    c1.c = c2.c + 100 up;
    c3.c = c2.c + 100 down;

    boxit.f1("\textit{feature 1}");
    boxit.f2("\textit{feature 2}");
    boxit.f3("\textit{feature 3}");

    f2.c = c2.c + 100 right;
    f1.c = f2.c + 40 up;
    f3.c = f2.c + 40 down;

    boxit.e1("Entity 1");
    boxit.e2("Entity 2");

    e1.c = f2.c + (100,30);
    e2.c = f2.c + (100,-30);

    drawunboxed(c1,c2,c3);
    drawunboxed(f1,f2,f3);
    drawunboxed(e1,e2);

    vardef connect(suffix a, b)(expr strength) = 
      draw a.c -- b.c
           cutbefore bpath a 
           cutafter  bpath b 
           withpen pencircle scaled ((strength+2)/4)
           withcolor ((strength+1)/2)[blue,red];
    enddef;

    connect(c1,f1,+1.0);
    connect(c1,f2,-0.5);
    connect(c1,f3,-0.2);

    connect(c2,f1,+0.6);
    connect(c2,f2,+0.3);
    connect(c2,f3,-0.9);

    % etc

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

As the `boxes` manual explains, the command `boxit.sss("Some text")` creates a box called `sss` centered at point `sss.c`.  You then specify the relations between the boxes, and the positions are fixed when you call `drawunboxed` (or `drawboxed`) with the list of box names.

I've then created a `connect` macro to draw the connections in a consistent manner.

If you wanted all the connections to run from the east of one box to the west of the next you could replace `draw a.c -- b.c` with `draw a.e -- b.w` and remove the `cutafter` and `cutbefore` lines.

I've shown you how to vary the thickness of the line by strength as well as to change the colour.